# Android Wear device selection box says "offline localhost:4444 minSdk (API 20) > deviceSdk (API 1)"

Tags: android, compilation, wear-os

I am trying to build android wear application, If I set minsdk to 20/21. It gives error below,

[image]

But if I set it to 19, I get following error:

```
/home/bhupinder/AndroidStudioProjects/MyWatch/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:0:0 Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 20 declared in library /home/bhupinder/AndroidStudioProjects/MyWatch/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.support/wearable/1.0.0/AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.wearable" to force usage
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 20 declared in library /home/bhupinder/AndroidStudioProjects/MyWatch/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.support/wearable/1.0.0/AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.wearable" to force usage
```

What should I do to run it? I am trying sample code from here => http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/how-to-create-a-custom-android-wear-watch-face/120

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error about API levels (deviceSdk = API 1). I fixed it by resetting the watch to factory settings (Settings > Reset device). When I paired it again with the phone the proper API level was reported.

Comment: I've seen this on phones when your computer is not authorized to debug via USB. I haven't tried this with watches, but resetting the debugging authorization on the watch (and maybe phone too) may work. On both  phone and watch the setting is at: Settings > Developer options -> Revoke (USB) debugging authorizations. Then when you reconnect the devices, you should get authorization prompts and you should confirm that you want to allow debugging. Once again, I didn't test this but it may work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the watch connected via Bluetooth Debugging?

This might solve your problem: http://melix.github.io/blog/2014/10/android-moto360.html